# how to replace anchor tag in commented code in html using java

Tags: java, html

I have a html content with lot of comments.
in html comments anchor tags are there.so i need to replace anchor starting tag
 with ^^ which are present in comment content.

```
**original content**
<html>
<body>
    <!-- somthing text <a href="google.com" >google</a> somthing
    asdf
    asdfasdf
    asdfasdfs
    -->

    <!-- somthing text <a href="google.com" >google</a> somthing
    asdf<!--
    asdfasdf
    asdfasdfs
    -->
    <a href="yahoo.com">yahoo</a>   
</body>
</html>

**Expected Content**
<html>
<body>
    <!-- somthing text ^^ href="google.com" >google</a> somthing
    asdf
    asdfasdf
    asdfasdfs
    -->

    <!-- somthing text ^^ href="google.com" >google</a> somthing
    asdf<!--
    asdfasdf ^^ href="google.com" >google</a>
    asdfasdfs
    -->
    <a href="yahoo.com">yahoo</a>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your html and describe what is the result you are willing to have?

Comment: just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex can help you on this case:

```
String html = "<your html>";
String regex = "(<!--[\\s\\w]+)(<a)(\\s*href=\\\"google\\.com\\\"\\s*>)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.replaceAll("$1^^$3"));
}
```

May be you want to edit the regex base on your case.

Comment: That's fine, just adjust by ur real case.